# Stateless ejb does not remove the pool

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jboss, ejb

I'm having problems with memory leaks, because EJBs are not being removed from the pool. The ejb is 3.0 and stateless.

```
In my jboss jmx-console 4.3, the statistics of a particular ejb looks like:

AvailableCount  30
MaxSize     30
CurrentSize     5727
CreateCount     5727
RemoveCount     0
```

My question is: Why the "Remove Count" is not increasing? And the "Current Size" is larger than the "MaxSize"?

Comment: @TiagoBraga  FYI - if you are using EAP, the you can contact JBoss support directly.

Comment: Ok, but I asked here to see if I could find a quick answer. thank you.

Comment: Moreover, I share the problem so that others who do not have support jboss can solve. :)

Answer (score 3):

Man you have hit a dreaded bug where SLSB are not cleared and leaked... We have faced this issue in Our Production environment a couple of weeks ago...

The only workaround even recommended by JBoss is to use `StrictMaxPool` instead of `ThreadLocalPool` for your SLSB. Choose the count wisely.

You should modify `ejb3-interceptors-aop.xml`

```
<domain name="Stateless Bean">
...
  <annotation expr="!class(@org.jboss.annotation.ejb.PoolClass)">
     @org.jboss.annotation.ejb.PoolClass (value=org.jboss.ejb3.StrictMaxPool.class, maxSize=30, timeout=10000)
  </annotation>
</domain>
```

Here are some links to give you some insight...

[Stateless session bean pooling in JBoss](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/EJBTHREE-1175?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel)

[New instance of resources injected on every onMessage MDB call](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-5345)

[ThreadlocalPool does not remove active BeanContext instances from InfinitePool](https://community.jboss.org/message/363520)

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

I have another project that has also EJBs and is properly removed from the Pool (The "Remove Count" increases with time). The only difference is that my current one has EJB Timers. Is it because of this that the bug occurs?

Comment: The "Remove Count" has not increased at any time. In this case, it is creating instances of ejb more slowly but reaches the limit.